# Jmeter same threads but different ramp up time crashes server?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm using Jmeter 2.13 and something interesting is happening for which I need some help. I did two test on website with settings

**test 1**

users: 500
ramp up time:60

result:smooth connections

**test 2**

users: 500
ramp up time:120

result: crashes java

All I know is the Apache java GUI crashes. I don't know how to troubleshoot what's causing the crash. I know there are some elements with GUI you can configure to observe Jmeter server health stats i.e threads, load etc.

Also, on the settings where it crashes, a single request is made every 0.24 seconds.

On test case 1 where it worked this equates to 0.12 seconds a single request is made.

If the calculations are correct, theoretically speaking, it shouldn't crash right? (because the difference in negligible)

Comment: What about the jmeter.log file? This usually captures the exceptions.
What is your loop count? or is it forever?

Comment: I just created a simple test and used 500 Users / 120 Ramp Up / Loop 500, and tested from my machine ( mbp ) and redline13 .  Both worked fine,  though my test server did not hold up since this simulated 250,000 * 2 test pages requested.   Here is output of result with 500 iterations, which I did terminate early [large test plan](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/15175)  and smaller version only 5 iterations [smaller test plan](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/15181).   Test plan can be downloaded from there.  To help really need more info about your test-plan.

Comment: loop was one in both cases. Thanks a lot for testing it at your own end.

Comment: and also explain did you perform in distributed way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: **don't use GUI mode to run a JMeter test**. Ever. Use GUI only for test development and debugging.

Running JMeter in non-GUI mode is fairly simple:

```
 jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/resultsfile.jtl
```

Once test finished you can open `resultsfile.jtl` with your favourite listener and analyse test results.

For more JMeter-side performance tips and tricks see [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](https://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide.